# Program stops working

Tags: c++, function

I was trying to make a function that took a paragraph and displays the first letters of each word. The program runs fine the first few times I run it, but in subsequent instances, stops working after the function executes. Here is the code:

```
//program that returns the first letter of each word in a paragraph
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void firstLetter(string, ostream&);

int main()
{
    string paragraph;

    cout<<"Enter a paragraph."<<endl;
    getline(cin, paragraph);

    firstLetter(paragraph, cout);

    return 0;
}

void firstLetter(string words, ostream& out)
{
    for(int i= 0; i < words.length(); i++){
        out<<words[i++]<<" ";

        while(words[i] != ' '){
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried deleting the .exe file and rebuilding the project, but it just ends up not working again after a few runs. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Follow what the program does with a debugger and the answer should become clear as day.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a human debugger.

Comment: @leemes SO is no human either.

Comment: @MarkGarcia You're right. I should have said: ... a human-driven debugger. ;)

Comment: I ran the debugger, it said program exited normally....

Comment: [removed comment] -- I misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: @user1949498, You have to step through and see what it's doing. Use the same input as when it crashed and you'll see something go awry soon enough.

Comment: The title of this question is unlikely to be useful to future visitors of the site. Too localized.

Answer (score 3):

The loop is the problem.

```
for(int i= 0; i < words.length(); i++){
    out<<words[i++]<<" ";

    while(words[i] != ' '){
        i++;
    }
}
```

You increment `i` in the increment expression (`i++`), but you also increment it in the `out <<...` expression. Your while loop can access invalid data here, as you are incrementing again after your previous check in the for-loop, as well as for every skipped letter. So sooner or later, you are accessing invalid data here, resulting in undefined behavior, or even a segmentation fault.

I expect you want to skip over non-spaces only if you didn't just output/skip the very last character (which is the case for the last word). This requires another check in the while loop:

```
    while(i < words.length() && words[i] != ' '){
        i++;
    }
```

There still is a problem with things like multiple spaces, dashes (if you don't want to output it) and other fancy typographical stuff... But I expect you don't need to consider these cases.

Comment: See my edit, it now corresponds to your problem (I first thought you want to skip multiple whitespaces...)

Comment: "One of them shouldn't increment" - that's not really the case here is it?

Comment: @Fraser Yeah, it's a remaining from my previous answer, when I misinterpreted the question. Thanks for this hint, gonna remove this line.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check that `i` has not exceeded the size of `words` in the `while` loop.

```
while(i < words.length() && words[i] != ' '){
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to assert that `i < words.length()` ***before*** accessing `words[i]` since `i` is increment elsewhere within the loop?

Comment: This means i < words.length() is checked twice

Comment: Well, it's checked every time the `while` loop cycles, which will be a lot more than before for a paragraph of more than 2 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with leemes.
Think you have 'hello, world'
the print should be 'h w', then error. because there's no ' ' after 'world', causing the while loop never end (and get to somewhere invalid), instead, you have a '\0'.
I suggest you check the '\0' and return your function.
like :

```
while(words[i] != ' ' && words[i] != '\0') 
{
i++;
}
```

(And I guess the fine cases you met should be those having a space in the end.)

Comment: A `std::string` doesn't have a `\0` in its internal data, at least an implementation doesn't have to. Accessing `words[words.length()]` (which would be the case here) is undefined behavior. For C-strings, your code is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the inner loop is endless when i exceeds the bounds of the string.

```
  void firstLetter(string words, ostream& out)
    {
        for(size_t i= 0, len = words.length(); ; i++){  // i < words.length() removed, it is checked in the inner loop
            out<<words[i]<<" ";

            while(words[i] != ' '){
                if( i == len-1 ) return;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an alternative I personaly would prefer to use:

```
#include <sstream>

    void firstLetter2(string words, ostream& out)
    {
        istringstream iss(words);

        while( ! iss.eof() )
        {
            string sWord;
            iss >> sWord >> ws;
            out<<sWord[0]<<' ';
        }
    }
```

Comment: You fell into the same trap I did :-)  You probably want to move your `if` to after your post-increment in the `while` loop to avoid accessing one-past-the-end.

Comment: @Fraser - No, it shouldn't matter because 'i' will never point at ' ' when at the end of the string, it will perform one more iteration before returning

Comment: So say `words.size()` is 8, and on entering the `while` loop, `i` is 7.  You increment and then access `words[8]`, which is past the end.  Also, if `words` ends in a space, by removing the check in the `for`, you access two-past-the-end in the `while` loop.

Comment: @Fraser - Yes and a slight change fixes it, thanks. I made an edit.

Comment: You still have a problem if `words` ends in `' '`.

Comment: Assume it doesn't, as it's also assumed spaces between words are a single space character, the given code of the post wouldn't work if there where multiple space characters between them. So assume this is the pattern, ends with no spaces as well. But if I had to choose a solution myself, I would prefer to use a stringstream to read the words.